# Should choose 32Inch or 27Inch for 2K WQHD PC Monitor?

Tags: pc, monitors, hdmi, display-port, video-game-console

I going to buy a Monitor, this gonna be my first monitor so I plan to get a monitor that could output Above Average Visual Experience.

**Main Requirements**:

- 2K WQHD (2560 x 1440 Resolution)
- Refresh Rate between 75Hz to 144Hz
- 24 Inch Size or Above

The **purpose of the monitor** is to:

1. Connect to my **ROG Strix Scar 2**, i7-8750H + RTX2070 Laptop **(with Mini Display Port)** to play High Graphic Game (eg. Monster Hunter World) in **2K Resolution**
2. Connect my **Nintendo Switch** (with HDMI Port) to play **Legend of Zelda** 
   (only able output 900P from Switch by Default) in **900P Resolution** or other Games in **1080P Resolution**.

The Monitor I found so far [ACER ED323QURA 32" Curve 2K WQHD](https://www.lazada.com.my/products/acer-ed323qura-32-curve-2k-wqhd-freesync-144hz-2k-gaming-monitor-i452464299-s689224606.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.5.1c273ab4uj411v&search=1) and My Budget is **RM1300 (around USD 310)**

**My Concerns and Uncertainty**:

1. I been come across some site [(Reddit Forum)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monitors/comments/9pvhaj/what_is_1080p_like_on_a_32inch_monitor/), mentioned that 2K WQHD 32Inch Monitor going have drawback of **Pixelation Issue** when sit close to the screen, so should I get 27Inch Monitor to eliminate the Issue or the **Pixelation Issue** not something can be highly noticeable and should ignore it and go for 32Inch Monitor?
2. If I try to let the 32Inch 2K Monitor to **display 900P/1080P** Resolution (for Nintendo Switch Game), will the Visual Quality decrease which cause visual **Blurry/Pixalation/etc**?

I just hope that the Monitor could support my **purpose of the monitor** without compromise the Visual Quality, will a 32 Inch 2K WQHD Monitor will surely doing fine without harming the visual experience? or should I consider other Monitor (lower Inch Size, etc)

Please do recommend me any Monitor that fit my Scenario and Use case the Best, thank you.

Comment: I'm using a 144 Hz 1080p 27" monitor - while the resolution isn't amazing (say, compared to 2k or 4k displays), it's more than fine for gaming.
2k at 32" still has higher DPI than my setup, so you should be fine.

As for the Switch, you'll always have some pixelation issues there - regardless of which size screen you use. The Switch's video output just doesn't have enough resolution for contemporary monitors.

Comment: @towe so Monitor is not recommended for play Switch Game? if I buy a 2K TV, will Switch output better image quality than Monitor?

Comment: No, the potential image quality will be held back in the same way as on your monitor. It won't be horrible, but you're obviously not fully using the 2k resolution. The screen size makes no difference in this, at least when you also adjust your distance from the screen.

Comment: To display 1080p sharply, you will need 4K (a multiple of 1080p), and to display 900p sharply you will need 1800p (a multiple of 900p). Obviously you cannot have both without having a ridiculous monitor resolution, and also 900p is not very common. So I would say 2K is fine.

In regards to pixelation issues, a 27 inch 1440p monitor has the same pixel density as a 21 inch 1080p monitor, if that's any use for you.

Comment: @rubyjunk is 32inch 1440p will have better pixel density than 27inch 1440p?

Comment: @IamaStudent Since the 32 inch has the same amount of pixels, but a larger screen, it will have a WORSE pixel density and therefore will appear more pixelated than a 27 inch screen at the same distance.

Comment: @rubyjunk if in a right view distance, pixelated issue wouldn't be notice in 32inch 1440p? as i not going to have this screen as desktop table setup, i would put on a floor, view from my bed instead.

Comment: @IamaStudent thats correct, at sufficient distance you probably won't be able to tell.